# Highchart does not produce the bar using highchart.visualize

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm just producing a dummy chart base on the html element. I'm referring the example shown on  the highchart here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

So i modified a bit to suit my need. Here the code

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        Highcharts.visualize = function(table, options) {               
            options.xAxis.categories = [];  // the categories           
            options.series           = [];  // the data series
            var candidateArray = [
                'Nuh',
                'Saleh',
                'Ibrahim',
                'Musa',
                'Ishak',
                'Harun',
                'Ilyas Ishak',
                'Zulkifli',
                'Idris',
                'Isa',
                'Muhammad'
            ];

            $('tbody tr', table).each( function(i) {
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * candidateArray.length);
                //options.xAxis.categories.push(candidateArray[randomNumber]);
                options.series[i] = {
                    name: candidateArray[randomNumber],
                    //name: 'Candidate Name',
                    type: 'column',
                    data: [{
                            x: candidateArray[randomNumber], 
                            y: Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
                          }]
                };
                console.log(options.series[i]);
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
            var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
                options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart',
                        backgroundColor: '#FBFBFB'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Top ' + $("#html5shim-2-out").html() + ' Best Candidate'
                    },
                    xAxis: {

                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'No. of PT'
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                                series: {
                                    borderRadius: 5        
                                }
                            },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                this.y +' '+ this.x.toLowerCase();
                        }
                    }
                };

            Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
    });
});
```

as you can see no chart generated after page loaded and am using the latest highchart library and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.1

thanks in advance for those willing to reply

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do?  Why are you still reading and passing dataArray when you do not seem to be reading from it anymore?  It appears that you are iterating over it but filling in your own values.  If you wanted to change the values in the table you should change them in the HTML section of the JSFiddle, rather than in the function itself.